# Cultivation manhwa where the protagonist goes to Earth to show his daughter her mother, and learns she's going to marry someone else

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

The main character and his daughter live in the upper world/realm but after his daughter asks where her mother is, they decide to go to the mortal realm to find her, just to find out that she is going to marry someone else
and apparently she does not recognize either the daughter or the main character.

Comment: When did you read this? Was it on a particular website? Is the non-upper-realm part on a medieval Earth? Fantasy? Modern? Futuristic?

Comment: its a modern cultivation Manhwa and I read it about a month ago but I deleted It on accident and I don't know the website anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Immortal Reverence Dad](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/immortal-reverence-dad)***. I was just looking for it and am sharing what I found.

> An undefeated immortal from three realms go to Earth to meet the mother of his daughter who they conceived when the immortal wandered into the woman's dream.

Comment: Can you share how it matches?